# EXCEL XOR multiple bits

Tags: excel, xor

I have two cells with a string of bits 0111010 and 0101011. I want to XOR the two together so that the resulting cell would be 0010001.

I know you can use this for boolean values

```
=OR(AND(A1,NOT(A2)),AND(A2,NOT(A1)))
```

but it doesn't work for a string of bits.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use VBA to do this. If you open VBA, create a new Module and enter the function

```
Public Function BITXOR(x As Long, y As Long)
    BITXOR = x Xor y
End Function
```

You can then use the DEC2BIN and BIN2DEC to convert from binary to decimal to run this function. For example:

Cell A1 = 0111010

Cell A2 = 0101011

```
=DEC2BIN(BITXOR(BIN2DEC(A1),BIN2DEC(A2)))
```

Comment: Thanks!

For other users, to use DEC2BIN go to Tools -> Addins -> Analysis toolpak.

To do VBA go to Tools -> Macros -> Visual Basic Editor

Comment: A bit late in the day, but for reference, VBA's bitwise operators can handle non-integral types as well (interpret the result as you will)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with VBA:

```vb
Public Function XOR_binary(b1, b2) As String
    Dim len_b1
    Dim len_b2
    Dim len_diff
    Dim i
    Dim bit1
    Dim bit2
    
    ' see if the two string are the same length. If not, add 0's to
    ' the beginning of the shorter string
    
    len_b1 = Len(b1)
    len_b2 = Len(b2)
    len_diff = len_b1 - len_b2
    
    Select Case len_diff
        Case Is < 0
            ' b2 is longer
            b1 = String(Abs(len_diff), "0") & b1
        Case Is = 0
            ' they're the same length
        Case Is > 0
            ' b1 is longer
            b2 = String(len_diff, "0") & b2
    End Select
    
    XOR_binary = ""
    
    For i = Len(b2) To 1 Step -1
        bit1 = CInt(Mid(b1, i, 1))
        bit2 = CInt(Mid(b2, i, 1))
        
        XOR_binary = CInt(bit1 Xor bit2) & XOR_binary
    Next i
    
End Function
```

Probably not the best implementation, but it works.

Using your example, `A3` contains:

```vb
=XOR_Binary(A1,A2)
```

The resulting string will have the same number of bits as the longest string you pass in.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution **without using VBA**:
`=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(MOD(INT(MID(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},1))+INT(MID(A2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},1)),2),{1000000,100000,10000,1000,100,10,1}),"0000000")`

This calculates the bitwise `XOR` using `SUMPRODUCT` and `TEXT` to turn it into a string of bits.

*Note:* this formula requires both input values to have length 7 (as per your own example) and the output will also have length 7.  To allow for different input lengths, simply implement the necessary truncation and/or padding.

---

You can choose to use some shorthand definitions:

- define `BitPositions` as `={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` (7-bit),
- define `BitStrings` as `={1000000,100000,10000,1000,100,10,1}` (7-bit),
- define `BitFormat` as `="0000000"` (7-bit),

then your formula can be made a bit more legible/shorter/cleaner:
`=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(MOD(INT(MID(A1,BitPositions,1))+INT(MID(A2,BitPositions,1)),2),BitStrings),BitFormat)`

This also makes it easier to work with larger strings of bits, e.g.:

- define `BitPositions` as `=ROW(INDIRECT("1:32"))` (32-bit),
- define `BitStrings` as `=10^(32-ROW(INDIRECT("1:32")))` (32-bit),
- define `BitFormat` as `=REPT("0",32)` (32-bit)

Should you wish to implement `NOT`/`OR`/`AND`/etc. then you can get your inspiration from these [formulas for the decimal counterparts](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/bitwise.html); here are [some more in-depth explanations](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/01/5-and-3-is-1.html) for `XOR` with `SUMPRODUCT` though it also uses decimal inputs.

Answer (score 0):

=1-(A1<>0)+(A2<>0) for each bit.

You can split it into individual columns for the above formula using this:
=MID(A1|7|1)
=MID(A1|6|1)
=MID(A1|5|1)
=MID(A1|4|1)
=MID(A1|3|1)
=MID(A1|2|1)
=MID(A1|1|1)
...

Comment: How do you do the for each bit part though?

Comment: =1-(A1<>0)+(A2<>0) for each bit. 
I had to modify this a bit to get it working now
=INT(ISODD((A1<>0)+(A2<>0)))

Its works for a cell with a 1 or 0 in it, so you have to split up whatever you are working on, like =mid(A1,8,1) ... like he said

Answer (score 0):

' this VBA returns a double that has to be formatted on the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function MYXOR(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Double
'r1 and r2 are expected as HEX; for example, 
'DEC2HEX(CODE("B")) returns ASCII of "B" as HEX
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  MYXOR = "&H" & r1.Value Xor "&H" & r2.Value
  GoTo CleanUp
ErrHandler:
  MYXOR = Err.Number
  Resume CleanUp
CleanUp:
' format the double being returned in MYXOR with TEXT(DEC2HEX(MYXOR(C9,F9)),"00000")
' number of leading zeroes according to the size of the HEX in r1 and r2
End Function
```