# logical operation of two excel arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, boolean

I would like to perform a logical operation of two arrays(cells A1, B1), using excel functions only(refer to the example).

A1 = {TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}

B1 = {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}

OR operation results in:

C1 = A1 OR B1 = {TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}

AND operation results in:

D1 = A1 AND B1 = {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}

Could it be done?

Comment: Is the entire array in A1, or is the range A1:A5 your array of true and false??

Comment: I know it can be done if the true false values are each in their own cell.  however I am not sure if it can be done if the array is manually entered into a single cell

Comment: Yes, the entire array in A1, as exemplified.

Comment: So A1 contains the TEXT string "{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}"? I don't see how a single cell could contain that array of Booleans. It could be stored in-formula, via e.g. =1>{0,0,1,1,0} within A1, though even in that case the actual cell value would only comprise a single entry, i.e. TRUE.

Comment: You could look at this (which goes into AND and OR as well as XOR) but describes the process using formulas as as 'painful' pre Excel 2013. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571807/how-do-i-perform-a-xor-calculation-of-two-binary-numbers-in-excel-2007

Comment: If, as I suspect, you've attempted to 'simplify' your problem using an example in which the arrays of Booleans are contained in actual cells (which isn't in fact possible) and that, in reality, the arrays to which you refer are derived using a single formula, e.g. =1>{0,0,1,1,0;0,1,0,1,0} (which results in the 2-row-by-5-column array {TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE;TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}), then, letting Rng stand for the above-mentioned formula, MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(Rng)),{1;1})>0 and MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(Rng)),{1;1})=2, both with CSE, would give the desired OR and AND arrays (though transposed).